# How to properly scale SVG (SVG is clipping)?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to use this SVG:

```html
      <svg class="img-fluid" id="outputsvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 16.4571, 36.0946); transform-origin: 50% 50%; cursor: move; max-height: none; transition: none 0s ease 0s;" width="1010" height="657" viewBox="0 0 20260 13200"><g id="l1zEqXlFURcLpqU3fGQvSiH" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" style="transform: none;"><g><path id="p1g1ALdrZ" d="M1930 13176 c0 -18 16 -29 30 -21 13 8 1 35 -16 35 -8 0 -14 -6 -14 -14z"></path><path id="pduVNP1hx" d="M2185 13140 c-4 -6 -4 -50 0 -96 9 -106 17 -108 88 -25 43 52 47 84 13 106 -33 22 -91 30 -101 15z"></path><path id="p6rZ45wEZ" d="M2071 13033 c1 -32 4 -69 8 -83 7 -22 8 -20 14 18 8 47 -1 122 -14 122 -5 0 -9 -26 -8 -57z"></path><path id="p15Wkt0VsD" d="M1923 13016 c-25 -26 -53 -120 -53 -176 0 -75 -46 -80 -64 -7 -12 46 -22 47 -29 5 -12 -68 -11 -402 1 -425 16 -29 15 -65 -3 -89 -8 -11 -15 -42 -15 -74 -2 -82 -18 -121 -58 -134 l-32 -11 21 -22 c19 -19 21 -27 14 -92 -6 -64 -9 -71 -29 -71 -11 -1 -32 -7 -46 -15 -39 -22 -46 -18 -60 31 -14 51 -9 61 35 66 47 5 39 32 -11 36 -33 2 -44 8 -53 28 -32 71 -64 -40 -57 -201 5 -135 25 -308 36 -315 8 -5 38 -195 59 -380 21 -177 34 -265 41 -270 4 -3 20 -79 35 -170 23 -137 29 -205 33 -404 4 -191 2 -240 -9 -246 -7 -5 -36 -12 -64 -15 -66 -9 -330 -65 -395 -84 -248 -71 -375 -125 -514 -217 -32 -21 -66 -43 -75 -49 -9 -5 -31 -22 -49 -37 -18 -16 -37 -28 -42 -28 -21 0 -221 -213 -246 -263 -9 -17 -31 -50 -49 -72 -17 -22 -44 -71 -59 -110 -15 -38 -41 -99 -58 -135 -46 -94 -87 -279 -88 -392 0 -28 -5 -48 -12 -50 -18 -6 -19 -639 0 -645 6 -3 12 -21 12 -41 0 -34 18 -140 39 -237 26 -119 33 -145 41 -145 4 0 14 -24 20 -52 7 -29 18 -64 25 -78 7 -14 15 -45 19 -70 9 -58 27 -111 45 -130 17 -18 81 -150 81 -167 0 -7 4 -13 8 -13 4 0 14 -17 21 -37 20 -57 74 -163 83 -163 4 0 17 -20 28 -44 11 -25 41 -75 66 -112 25 -37 54 -87 65 -110 10 -24 30 -53 44 -66 14 -12 37 -41 50 -65 14 -23 33 -48 43 -55 9 -7 29 -32 44 -55 15 -23 42 -52 59 -65 16 -12 39 -37 49 -53 11 -17 32 -38 47 -45 15 -8 69 -55 120 -105 50 -49 130 -121 177 -160 47 -38 86 -73 86 -77 0 -4 5 -8 11 -8 10 0 70 -47 154 -122 23 -21 47 -38 54 -38 6 0 30 -17 54 -38 23 -21 49 -41 58 -45 10 -3 53 -28 98 -56 44 -28 85 -51 91 -51 6 0 18 -4 28 -9 9 -4 35 -17 56 -27 22 -10 55 -31 74 -46 18 -15 57 -34 86 -42 29 -9 70 -30 92 -47 46 -37 73 -49 134 -59 25 -5 79 -24 120 -43 144 -66 228 -79 532 -81 289 -1 400 17 582 98 32 14 65 26 74 26 8 0 38 24 67 53 29 28 58 57 64 62 51 45 124 136 147 183 15 31 31 59 35 62 4 3 13 37 19 75 11 65 21 96 56 169 19 40 17 65 -7 84 -16 14 -22 35 -29 107 -10 103 -30 195 -42 195 -4 0 -8 6 -8 14 0 20 -36 129 -55 168 -21 40 -104 119 -163 154 -57 34 -194 74 -252 74 -51 0 -154 -33 -210 -68 -19 -12 -48 -43 -65 -69 -16 -26 -35 -54 -42 -61 -7 -7 -13 -18 -13 -23 0 -12 -67 -45 -108 -52 -86 -17 -406 87 -472 153 -11 11 -27 20 -36 20 -9 0 -28 8 -42 18 -15 10 -40 24 -57 32 -16 8 -56 35 -88 60 -33 25 -69 52 -80 60 -32 21 -197 169 -235 210 -17 19 -35 44 -38 55 -4 11 -18 30 -33 43 -78 69 -116 110 -148 158 -20 30 -40 54 -44 54 -5 0 -23 29 -40 66 -17 36 -42 77 -55 91 -22 23 -57 89 -93 173 -6 14 -20 39 -31 55 -36 56 -50 97 -50 151 0 79 -2 78 290 71 235 -7 309 -12 520 -37 52 -6 140 -15 195 -21 55 -5 140 -13 188 -18 130 -14 2003 -15 2162 -2 346 29 503 50 546 72 9 5 50 13 90 19 41 6 90 16 109 22 32 10 33 11 12 19 -13 5 -75 4 -140 -1 -233 -20 -280 -23 -306 -16 -25 6 -27 11 -24 44 3 34 1 37 -25 40 -36 4 -87 -31 -80 -57 3 -12 -2 -23 -14 -29 -10 -5 -185 -12 -400 -14 l-383 -5 -22 24 c-12 12 -32 23 -45 23 -13 0 -62 10 -109 21 -71 18 -92 20 -123 10 -43 -12 -202 -31 -273 -31 -41 0 -47 3 -50 23 -2 12 -13 26 -25 32 -77 33 38 45 447 44 370 -1 876 17 918 33 13 4 20 13 17 19 -5 7 -58 10 -154 9 -214 -3 -264 -1 -281 10 -13 9 -13 11 0 19 22 15 84 20 380 31 281 11 442 24 468 39 31 18 -43 19 -413 9 -466 -13 -548 -13 -847 -3 -184 6 -238 11 -238 21 0 15 39 21 183 28 53 3 105 9 115 14 9 5 136 12 282 15 313 8 412 19 451 51 24 21 41 23 178 29 83 4 182 11 219 17 37 5 103 14 146 21 93 13 124 33 79 50 -20 8 -85 8 -238 0 -447 -24 -662 -31 -928 -31 -260 0 -276 1 -282 19 -13 43 15 65 67 50 57 -16 102 -11 124 14 18 20 36 24 150 35 141 14 179 27 179 57 0 19 -6 20 -90 19 -69 -1 -102 -7 -137 -23 -52 -23 -89 -26 -169 -11 -59 10 -149 49 -149 64 0 16 -71 76 -96 82 -15 4 -34 -2 -55 -17 -44 -31 -109 -31 -174 0 -44 22 -165 133 -165 152 0 5 -40 49 -90 99 -67 69 -93 102 -101 133 -7 23 -20 49 -30 58 -31 28 -73 129 -73 178 -1 44 0 46 29 49 51 4 75 12 75 23 0 6 -38 49 -86 96 -58 58 -94 103 -112 141 -14 32 -32 63 -38 69 -15 16 -44 139 -44 187 0 19 6 47 12 62 11 23 10 28 -1 32 -8 3 -28 18 -44 34 -25 23 -33 43 -43 96 -6 37 -23 112 -38 167 -14 54 -26 109 -26 122 0 13 -4 23 -10 23 -5 0 -10 18 -10 41 0 36 -15 100 -41 170 -6 14 -21 37 -34 52 -29 31 -30 34 -10 53 20 21 19 41 -4 61 -16 13 -19 25 -14 64 7 59 -11 136 -39 166 -16 17 -19 30 -14 54 6 30 -18 89 -36 89 -13 0 -9 39 5 47 36 21 25 126 -17 168 -38 38 -50 78 -33 112 13 24 13 31 1 48 -8 10 -14 42 -14 71 0 41 -5 58 -28 86 -34 43 -73 211 -53 231 17 17 13 45 -9 59 -21 14 -27 43 -10 53 18 11 11 36 -20 75 -27 35 -29 43 -29 119 0 61 -4 92 -19 124 -12 24 -22 75 -26 120 -3 43 -10 86 -16 97 -5 10 -10 32 -10 49 0 17 -4 31 -9 31 -5 0 -11 28 -15 63 -8 92 -23 183 -31 197 -5 8 -28 9 -74 5 -106 -10 -111 -12 -111 -44 0 -41 -9 -61 -29 -61 -17 0 -61 50 -61 70 0 5 -6 10 -14 10 -22 0 -29 -100 -16 -240 6 -69 13 -133 16 -143 9 -28 -5 -87 -20 -87 -19 0 -23 15 -31 111 -4 46 -11 89 -15 94 -4 6 -11 44 -15 85 -3 41 -13 86 -21 102 -8 15 -14 56 -14 95 0 75 -9 143 -19 143 -3 0 -16 -11 -28 -24z m-57 -290 c8 -31 1 -79 -11 -83 -12 -4 -45 52 -45 76 0 38 46 44 56 7z m-216 -992 c13 -34 13 -111 -1 -120 -28 -17 -63 84 -46 131 10 24 36 18 47 -11z m100 -1986 c22 -41 5 -51 -86 -50 -89 1 -111 13 -74 43 59 45 136 49 160 7z m151 -550 c7 -13 15 -25 18 -28 11 -9 57 -122 76 -188 16 -55 17 -65 4 -73 -19 -12 -411 1 -469 16 -27 7 -46 18 -48 27 -3 15 37 66 96 121 35 34 254 146 284 147 18 0 31 -7 39 -22z m138 -348 c12 -6 21 -18 21 -27 0 -13 -8 -14 -52 -9 -29 4 -88 9 -130 13 -43 3 -78 9 -78 13 0 4 10 12 23 19 27 14 186 8 216 -9z m49 -158 c3 -10 -4 -13 -24 -10 -15 2 -29 9 -32 16 -3 10 4 13 24 10 15 -2 29 -9 32 -16z m1952 -602 c0 -23 -80 -26 -88 -2 -2 8 10 12 42 12 25 0 46 -4 46 -10z m323 -9 c18 -18 -11 -32 -58 -29 -34 3 -41 7 -43 27 -4 23 -2 24 43 19 26 -3 52 -11 58 -17z m-2233 -42 c0 -5 -9 -9 -20 -9 -22 0 -27 16 -7 23 15 5 27 -1 27 -14z m315 -14 c188 -21 265 -35 265 -47 0 -12 -137 -7 -315 11 -122 13 -155 23 -155 47 0 13 7 15 33 10 17 -3 95 -13 172 -21z m1005 -85 c0 -16 -7 -20 -30 -20 -49 0 -37 37 13 39 11 1 17 -6 17 -19z"></path><path id="pIGwaQ1Ba" d="M1490 12228 c0 -17 27 -44 36 -35 3 3 -3 16 -15 28 -16 18 -21 19 -21 7z"></path><path id="p49jB9PQa" d="M5743 8653 c-21 -8 -15 -43 7 -43 29 0 70 21 70 37 0 13 -50 17 -77 6z"></path><path id="p16WqsLHzF" d="M5137 8601 c-40 -5 -74 -14 -84 -24 -15 -15 -14 -16 11 -23 15 -3 86 -2 158 4 122 10 164 21 140 36 -17 11 -154 15 -225 7z"></path><path id="pNQJFLDID" d="M4718 8591 c-68 -7 -77 -14 -46 -35 49 -32 270 -29 302 4 34 35 -87 49 -256 31z"></path><path id="pa3zUtl9C" d="M4827 8502 c-10 -2 -16 -9 -14 -15 5 -16 36 -22 48 -10 13 13 -11 31 -34 25z"></path><path id="p1AW5gL8fA" d="M5020 8490 c0 -5 16 -10 35 -10 19 0 35 5 35 10 0 6 -16 10 -35 10 -19 0 -35 -4 -35 -10z"></path><path id="pVNxMxpZT" d="M4463 8483 c-34 -6 -28 -20 14 -34 23 -7 61 -9 104 -5 78 7 101 14 96 30 -4 11 -169 18 -214 9z"></path><path id="pBonj5uO9" d="M5278 8073 c12 -2 30 -2 40 0 9 3 -1 5 -23 4 -22 0 -30 -2 -17 -4z"></path><path id="pmyqrY3s3" d="M4210 7941 c0 -14 27 -21 76 -21 32 0 44 4 44 15 0 12 -13 15 -60 15 -33 0 -60 -4 -60 -9z"></path><path id="pNKO1LRoa" d="M17902 7595 c-360 -10 -415 -14 -429 -28 -15 -15 -16 -25 -4 -94 7 -43 17 -79 22 -81 5 -2 9 -10 9 -18 0 -8 15 -79 34 -157 19 -78 37 -162 41 -186 4 -25 13 -50 20 -57 11 -12 85 -294 85 -327 0 -8 4 -17 10 -19 5 -1 16 -32 24 -68 24 -110 70 -285 76 -290 4 -3 26 -92 50 -197 24 -106 46 -193 50 -193 7 0 55 -186 80 -312 6 -32 15 -58 19 -58 4 0 15 -23 25 -50 10 -28 22 -53 28 -56 33 -20 1091 1 1293 25 225 28 347 60 477 126 147 74 268 182 328 290 18 33 36 62 40 65 5 3 17 33 29 67 46 135 56 458 20 598 -12 44 -26 103 -33 130 -6 28 -24 73 -39 100 -16 28 -35 65 -43 83 -7 18 -23 45 -34 60 -12 15 -37 52 -57 82 -64 98 -260 278 -355 326 -20 11 -56 35 -80 55 -36 30 -66 42 -180 73 -75 20 -151 36 -170 36 -18 0 -51 5 -73 10 -112 28 -203 40 -364 50 -97 6 -200 15 -230 21 -63 11 -113 10 -669 -6z m1027 -626 c52 -7 102 -21 129 -35 25 -13 50 -24 57 -24 7 0 20 -9 30 -20 10 -11 23 -20 29 -20 26 0 136 -123 168 -188 18 -37 35 -69 39 -72 17 -12 40 -137 45 -247 9 -151 -2 -182 -101 -286 -53 -56 -107 -78 -224 -89 -137 -13 -371 -5 -382 14 -5 7 -14 37 -20 66 -7 28 -15 52 -19 52 -5 0 -10 15 -13 33 -9 60 -77 311 -86 316 -10 7 -24 73 -46 226 -9 61 -22 130 -30 154 -18 55 -19 107 -2 118 35 23 255 24 426 2z"></path><path id="pupxqotTw" d="M11810 7570 c-63 -4 -208 -11 -323 -15 -156 -6 -210 -12 -219 -22 -14 -17 5 -138 32 -198 9 -22 34 -107 55 -190 21 -82 41 -152 45 -155 6 -5 35 -108 73 -260 11 -47 24 -87 27 -90 4 -3 26 -81 50 -175 24 -93 46 -172 50 -175 5 -3 27 -88 50 -190 24 -102 46 -187 50 -190 7 -5 72 -240 86 -310 3 -19 10 -37 13 -40 4 -3 15 -36 24 -75 10 -38 24 -76 33 -85 12 -12 59 -16 283 -18 286 -4 506 9 540 30 14 9 21 23 21 45 0 18 -4 33 -9 33 -5 0 -17 35 -26 78 -9 42 -26 111 -37 152 -11 41 -23 85 -25 98 -3 12 -9 22 -14 22 -5 0 -9 6 -9 13 1 22 -84 322 -93 328 -4 3 -26 77 -47 165 -22 87 -44 168 -49 179 -6 11 -29 90 -52 175 -23 85 -45 157 -49 160 -4 3 -18 50 -30 105 -29 129 -59 225 -69 225 -5 0 -11 10 -14 23 -28 129 -80 301 -98 321 -21 24 -97 48 -137 44 -9 -1 -69 -5 -132 -8z"></path><path id="pCYjMKKPS" d="M14439 7576 c-2 -2 -337 -7 -744 -11 -407 -4 -807 -10 -890 -14 l-150 -6 -3 -34 c-4 -34 37 -271 48 -281 8 -7 27 -75 63 -225 17 -71 35 -132 38 -135 6 -4 66 -238 84 -330 4 -19 11 -37 15 -40 5 -3 27 -79 49 -170 23 -90 45 -167 49 -170 5 -3 14 -32 21 -65 28 -133 72 -311 81 -330 6 -11 24 -80 40 -153 32 -141 39 -161 76 -201 l23 -24 1055 6 c854 5 1061 9 1084 19 25 13 27 17 25 73 -1 32 -7 61 -12 64 -5 4 -15 29 -21 56 -24 113 -71 285 -85 312 -8 15 -15 33 -15 40 0 6 -7 19 -17 28 -15 15 -68 17 -592 15 -693 -2 -768 0 -781 20 -5 8 -10 50 -10 93 l0 77 68 0 c240 1 786 13 885 20 122 8 147 17 147 54 1 26 -72 329 -80 336 -3 3 -14 26 -24 53 -10 26 -26 52 -36 57 -12 6 -224 10 -565 10 -351 0 -553 4 -565 10 -22 12 -45 80 -55 162 -6 44 -4 57 10 68 14 11 132 15 651 22 461 6 644 12 672 21 36 12 37 13 35 61 -1 32 -8 55 -21 70 -22 22 -40 81 -68 211 -9 44 -27 104 -40 133 -13 29 -24 56 -24 61 0 18 -84 30 -246 36 -94 3 -172 3 -175 1z"></path><path id="pvViZXaG1" d="M15545 7559 c-110 -3 -208 -7 -217 -8 -13 -1 -18 -10 -18 -28 -1 -32 71 -346 80 -353 4 -3 12 -34 19 -70 19 -93 70 -292 80 -311 21 -37 71 -203 71 -234 0 -41 20 -138 30 -145 7 -5 91 -345 90 -367 0 -7 5 -13 10 -13 6 0 10 -8 10 -17 0 -26 83 -387 91 -393 3 -3 9 -25 12 -50 9 -65 35 -147 52 -164 24 -24 105 -28 447 -24 299 3 325 5 356 23 25 15 32 26 32 51 0 18 -4 34 -8 36 -8 3 -52 166 -82 301 -7 31 -16 57 -20 57 -4 0 -13 28 -19 63 -21 111 -72 312 -80 317 -5 3 -25 82 -45 175 -21 94 -43 184 -51 200 -40 88 -77 304 -57 333 7 10 111 15 458 22 477 10 602 16 624 30 8 5 13 23 12 45 -2 45 -29 183 -42 210 -5 11 -20 65 -34 120 -41 160 -49 184 -65 192 -19 9 -1456 11 -1736 2z"></path><path id="peMf8lJn7" d="M3635 7540 c-150 -6 -175 -12 -175 -40 0 -18 46 -93 61 -98 5 -2 9 -8 9 -14 0 -14 81 -130 101 -145 9 -7 27 -32 39 -55 12 -24 37 -60 56 -80 18 -20 46 -56 61 -80 15 -24 33 -47 39 -53 6 -5 28 -34 48 -62 21 -29 41 -53 45 -53 3 0 26 -33 51 -72 24 -40 49 -76 56 -81 7 -4 27 -31 44 -60 18 -28 39 -59 46 -67 13 -14 72 -93 104 -140 8 -13 20 -28 26 -34 6 -6 23 -32 38 -58 15 -27 32 -48 37 -48 5 0 22 -24 39 -52 16 -29 42 -67 59 -85 16 -17 44 -55 62 -82 18 -28 36 -51 41 -51 4 0 8 -5 8 -10 0 -6 18 -35 40 -64 22 -29 40 -58 40 -63 0 -6 6 -13 14 -16 7 -3 25 -25 39 -49 14 -25 39 -58 54 -75 15 -16 41 -54 57 -84 27 -48 118 -176 136 -189 3 -3 25 -31 48 -62 38 -51 46 -57 89 -64 27 -5 197 -8 378 -9 424 0 396 -14 430 205 20 136 47 264 55 270 13 10 90 357 90 407 0 13 3 23 8 23 8 0 47 165 57 240 15 115 39 240 47 240 4 0 8 12 8 28 0 15 16 104 36 197 19 94 38 185 41 203 3 17 9 32 13 32 4 0 15 39 24 88 41 223 66 236 104 52 38 -182 66 -295 74 -301 5 -3 19 -52 32 -110 13 -57 32 -138 41 -179 10 -41 21 -77 24 -80 4 -3 26 -84 49 -180 24 -96 47 -184 52 -195 14 -28 70 -316 70 -356 0 -34 20 -111 31 -119 4 -3 14 -39 24 -80 40 -171 65 -258 90 -308 40 -82 51 -84 334 -79 130 3 418 7 641 11 725 11 763 14 924 90 161 76 255 156 301 256 48 102 66 249 45 359 -12 64 -57 177 -79 200 -9 10 -42 48 -75 84 -32 37 -63 67 -69 67 -6 0 -18 6 -26 14 -9 8 -53 33 -98 55 -45 23 -85 46 -89 52 -12 20 7 58 50 101 43 41 96 127 96 154 0 7 8 20 18 30 14 15 17 37 16 152 0 87 -4 136 -12 141 -16 9 -32 156 -32 293 0 96 -3 120 -17 134 -15 15 -47 16 -367 11 -193 -3 -364 -9 -379 -13 -53 -13 -62 -43 -58 -189 9 -327 7 -390 -13 -426 -10 -19 -35 -47 -54 -63 -32 -28 -41 -30 -161 -38 -69 -5 -186 -6 -259 -2 -132 6 -134 6 -145 33 -6 14 -14 28 -17 31 -10 10 -28 75 -55 195 -14 66 -31 129 -36 140 -5 11 -22 70 -38 130 -15 61 -36 125 -45 142 -27 53 -77 58 -446 46 -173 -5 -385 -6 -470 -2 -207 10 -717 -3 -747 -19 -18 -10 -23 -22 -23 -52 0 -22 -9 -56 -20 -76 -12 -20 -25 -59 -30 -88 -6 -31 -18 -58 -31 -68 -20 -17 -78 -25 -124 -19 -11 2 -180 6 -375 10 -195 4 -363 10 -372 15 -10 4 -20 16 -23 25 -3 9 -27 41 -55 71 -27 29 -56 68 -65 86 -8 18 -21 39 -28 46 -6 8 -19 27 -27 43 -13 25 -24 31 -65 37 -60 8 -395 7 -590 -2z m1533 -826 l92 -7 0 -31 c0 -17 -7 -78 -16 -136 -8 -58 -17 -126 -21 -153 -3 -26 -10 -50 -14 -53 -5 -3 -9 -14 -9 -25 0 -10 -6 -19 -14 -19 -15 0 -46 26 -46 38 0 4 -16 25 -36 47 -20 22 -48 58 -63 80 -14 22 -34 49 -44 60 -10 11 -32 44 -49 75 -17 30 -35 58 -40 61 -5 4 -8 17 -6 30 2 20 10 25 48 30 68 9 118 10 218 3z m2827 -428 c71 -19 123 -48 179 -101 47 -45 49 -48 54 -114 l4 -68 -45 -45 c-25 -25 -63 -52 -84 -59 -53 -19 -513 -20 -535 -1 -9 7 -19 31 -22 55 -11 68 -39 182 -47 187 -4 3 -10 30 -14 62 -7 52 -5 57 16 69 41 22 88 27 269 28 117 0 191 -4 225 -13z"></path><path id="pyot3NXBr" d="M9095 7541 c-64 -11 -68 -16 -62 -79 7 -65 67 -325 77 -332 4 -3 11 -21 15 -40 21 -101 67 -288 75 -305 10 -21 72 -270 84 -339 4 -21 12 -46 17 -55 5 -9 27 -90 49 -181 22 -91 44 -174 50 -185 5 -11 27 -96 50 -190 22 -93 45 -179 49 -190 16 -35 41 -118 41 -135 0 -9 7 -40 15 -68 15 -48 19 -52 58 -63 55 -16 1941 -14 1999 1 59 16 73 46 60 123 -20 110 -60 272 -75 302 -8 17 -25 54 -38 83 -12 29 -29 58 -37 65 -12 9 -155 12 -601 12 -670 0 -650 -2 -675 73 -9 26 -19 69 -22 97 -10 90 -41 84 471 94 248 5 459 12 470 16 64 21 67 26 60 80 -3 27 -12 62 -20 78 -8 15 -25 85 -40 155 -34 166 -46 193 -95 215 -35 15 -89 17 -497 17 -252 -1 -473 2 -490 6 -42 8 -48 17 -63 89 -7 33 -16 65 -20 70 -4 6 -27 89 -51 185 -23 96 -46 177 -50 180 -4 3 -15 34 -24 69 -23 90 -44 138 -63 147 -21 9 -663 14 -717 5z"></path><path id="pRLgLge5l" d="M6338 5483 c-23 -27 -83 -141 -109 -208 -29 -75 -55 -105 -89 -105 -38 0 -118 -29 -133 -48 -7 -10 -21 -22 -32 -28 -10 -6 -23 -25 -27 -42 -6 -22 -22 -39 -57 -61 -27 -16 -60 -43 -72 -60 -19 -25 -49 -48 -146 -108 -13 -7 -23 -21 -23 -29 0 -14 7 -15 48 -8 80 15 336 11 355 -5 19 -15 24 -115 8 -126 -5 -3 -96 -9 -203 -14 -212 -10 -278 -24 -314 -69 -21 -25 -25 -26 -177 -33 -87 -5 -166 -13 -178 -20 l-23 -12 23 -18 c12 -10 43 -21 69 -24 171 -24 359 -60 495 -95 88 -22 190 -45 227 -51 96 -15 154 -39 204 -86 46 -43 81 -117 92 -196 3 -23 10 -51 15 -62 4 -11 15 -67 24 -125 8 -58 19 -125 24 -150 46 -232 55 -276 61 -280 8 -6 36 -126 45 -190 13 -94 44 -232 55 -240 9 -6 68 -194 76 -240 4 -19 12 -44 18 -55 7 -11 18 -40 26 -65 7 -25 17 -49 20 -55 4 -5 17 -44 30 -85 13 -41 30 -86 37 -100 7 -14 13 -31 13 -38 0 -21 42 -186 50 -197 4 -5 13 -32 20 -60 7 -27 17 -54 21 -60 19 -21 8 -35 -26 -35 -63 0 -164 78 -165 127 0 44 -111 79 -161 53 -10 -6 -47 -15 -82 -20 -55 -8 -182 -40 -274 -68 -18 -6 -43 -18 -55 -26 -12 -9 -28 -16 -35 -16 -7 0 -34 -10 -61 -23 -133 -66 -193 -104 -258 -165 -64 -61 -72 -74 -94 -142 -12 -41 -27 -79 -32 -85 -4 -5 -8 -18 -8 -30 0 -11 -14 -58 -31 -105 -17 -47 -36 -104 -43 -127 -6 -23 -15 -45 -19 -49 -11 -11 -8 -134 3 -134 6 0 10 -9 10 -19 0 -44 41 -110 111 -179 40 -40 77 -72 82 -72 5 0 21 -8 35 -19 42 -29 233 -126 277 -141 22 -7 72 -28 110 -45 39 -18 86 -36 105 -40 19 -4 71 -17 115 -30 196 -58 398 -89 685 -105 96 -6 213 -15 260 -20 47 -6 149 -14 227 -19 l143 -8 57 -44 c32 -24 104 -90 160 -146 56 -57 105 -103 110 -103 5 0 20 -18 32 -40 30 -53 41 -59 206 -115 129 -44 145 -47 205 -41 130 13 289 78 321 130 10 16 21 47 24 68 4 21 11 38 16 38 5 0 9 14 9 30 0 17 -4 30 -9 30 -5 0 -12 19 -16 43 -4 23 -20 68 -36 100 -16 31 -34 77 -40 102 -6 25 -15 45 -19 45 -11 0 -31 76 -24 94 9 25 69 57 163 88 127 42 385 172 430 216 20 20 50 44 65 52 16 8 41 27 55 42 14 16 30 28 36 28 5 0 46 35 90 76 44 42 92 84 106 93 29 18 102 105 137 161 18 32 30 47 71 96 5 6 28 46 51 90 24 43 48 84 54 89 14 13 76 147 76 165 0 21 23 80 31 80 8 0 30 98 61 275 30 174 32 448 4 575 -25 116 -55 210 -66 210 -5 0 -21 23 -36 51 -25 50 -78 114 -138 168 -16 14 -50 47 -76 72 -26 25 -80 67 -121 94 -41 26 -87 65 -104 85 -28 35 -134 120 -150 120 -10 0 -92 69 -139 117 -23 24 -57 48 -76 54 -19 7 -69 36 -112 66 -42 29 -80 53 -85 53 -6 0 -18 9 -27 19 -10 11 -24 17 -31 15 -17 -7 -7 -43 16 -57 24 -15 24 -27 1 -27 -23 0 -122 96 -134 131 -4 9 -31 28 -62 43 -31 15 -56 32 -56 37 0 5 -5 9 -12 9 -6 0 -19 6 -27 14 -9 8 -70 42 -136 75 -66 34 -138 76 -160 95 -59 48 -184 123 -294 176 -35 16 -83 46 -107 65 -23 19 -45 35 -49 35 -3 0 -35 22 -71 50 -36 27 -76 53 -90 56 -33 8 -100 43 -140 71 -33 24 -140 73 -158 73 -6 0 -27 13 -46 29 -19 15 -45 31 -58 35 -12 4 -34 18 -50 30 -15 12 -61 43 -103 69 -48 30 -87 63 -108 92 -18 25 -41 49 -51 55 -10 5 -21 23 -25 39 -7 35 -20 47 -58 56 -15 4 -40 21 -55 38 -15 16 -44 48 -64 71 -21 22 -38 43 -38 47 0 11 -131 93 -171 107 -19 6 -50 12 -67 12 -18 0 -55 9 -84 20 -65 25 -81 25 -100 3z m1037 -900 c105 -52 176 -92 202 -114 10 -9 41 -27 68 -40 59 -28 199 -108 270 -154 47 -31 136 -75 150 -75 13 0 170 -122 185 -144 8 -11 36 -41 63 -66 50 -49 56 -60 32 -60 -9 0 -15 -9 -15 -24 0 -35 -15 -40 -63 -23 -23 8 -70 18 -104 21 -57 5 -134 34 -298 112 -28 13 -56 24 -63 24 -16 0 -134 58 -193 95 -23 15 -81 47 -129 71 -47 24 -97 55 -110 70 -14 14 -35 30 -47 35 -12 4 -32 28 -44 51 -12 24 -30 54 -40 67 -22 27 -25 61 -6 61 10 0 91 -40 267 -132 25 -12 72 -35 105 -50 33 -14 69 -35 79 -47 18 -20 56 -28 69 -15 12 13 -13 41 -42 47 -16 3 -57 30 -91 59 -34 29 -77 62 -95 73 -18 11 -53 36 -79 54 -25 19 -79 53 -119 74 -76 42 -107 64 -107 79 0 17 63 -3 155 -49z m136 -888 c19 -8 41 -19 49 -25 26 -16 244 -117 270 -125 14 -4 43 -20 65 -34 66 -42 70 -45 122 -73 27 -15 62 -43 77 -62 15 -20 33 -36 40 -36 18 0 232 -144 273 -182 18 -17 48 -41 67 -52 42 -26 216 -167 216 -175 0 -4 22 -30 49 -59 70 -74 76 -98 76 -292 0 -154 -2 -168 -24 -210 -13 -25 -30 -49 -37 -53 -8 -4 -14 -12 -14 -16 0 -18 -73 -116 -93 -127 -12 -6 -42 -22 -67 -34 -25 -13 -54 -31 -66 -41 -11 -11 -42 -26 -70 -35 -27 -9 -53 -20 -59 -24 -23 -17 -174 -40 -265 -40 -90 0 -101 2 -127 24 -17 14 -35 44 -42 68 -7 24 -16 45 -20 48 -4 3 -22 48 -40 100 -18 52 -42 111 -54 130 -11 19 -28 73 -38 120 -25 121 -55 223 -78 262 -18 31 -41 108 -70 238 -7 30 -16 64 -21 75 -5 11 -18 63 -31 115 -12 52 -33 126 -46 164 -12 38 -23 77 -23 87 0 9 -4 19 -9 21 -9 3 -71 222 -71 248 0 14 22 12 61 -5z"></path><path id="p4LCLMGOM" d="M15500 4862 c-107 -7 -120 -12 -120 -40 0 -38 52 -296 61 -302 10 -7 32 -96 69 -272 17 -79 34 -152 40 -163 5 -11 20 -65 34 -120 13 -55 31 -125 40 -155 9 -30 16 -70 16 -87 0 -18 4 -33 9 -33 5 0 28 -77 51 -172 22 -95 45 -177 49 -183 5 -5 14 -32 19 -60 40 -186 84 -365 96 -390 8 -16 22 -56 32 -89 29 -92 11 -88 422 -94 551 -7 1003 23 1212 82 47 13 137 48 200 79 91 44 128 68 180 119 91 88 116 122 158 208 21 41 39 77 42 80 20 18 32 107 37 273 5 157 3 202 -12 273 -10 46 -21 84 -25 84 -5 0 -11 19 -15 42 -4 23 -49 126 -101 228 -92 186 -93 187 -181 267 -105 97 -248 203 -273 203 -5 0 -38 15 -72 33 -69 37 -121 57 -213 81 -33 9 -100 28 -150 42 -167 47 -266 55 -740 60 -242 2 -528 5 -635 7 -107 1 -211 1 -230 -1z m1335 -612 c102 -19 188 -51 240 -90 62 -47 125 -110 125 -125 0 -3 13 -23 29 -46 16 -22 32 -53 36 -68 3 -16 15 -38 26 -50 18 -19 22 -43 30 -159 11 -166 3 -216 -49 -291 -31 -45 -52 -62 -113 -93 -88 -45 -132 -55 -270 -64 -119 -7 -242 7 -269 31 -10 9 -24 36 -31 61 -7 24 -17 44 -21 44 -4 0 -8 8 -8 19 0 10 -11 67 -25 127 -14 60 -32 141 -40 179 -8 39 -19 79 -25 90 -13 30 -58 228 -70 318 -14 93 -2 123 52 130 53 8 317 -1 383 -13z"></path><path id="pgNfxbzl3" d="M11265 4851 c-295 -8 -278 2 -310 -184 -27 -156 24 -141 -492 -142 -479 0 -456 -3 -493 57 -9 16 -32 45 -52 66 -19 20 -43 51 -54 67 -10 17 -31 44 -46 60 -15 17 -28 33 -28 36 0 3 -18 12 -40 19 -49 16 -688 8 -733 -9 -23 -9 -27 -15 -22 -34 8 -27 52 -94 82 -125 12 -13 37 -47 55 -75 18 -29 38 -55 44 -60 7 -4 27 -31 45 -60 17 -28 42 -61 54 -72 12 -11 39 -45 58 -75 20 -30 54 -75 74 -99 21 -24 42 -51 47 -60 5 -9 20 -27 32 -39 13 -13 35 -45 50 -70 15 -26 40 -59 56 -75 15 -15 28 -31 28 -35 0 -5 18 -28 40 -50 22 -23 45 -52 51 -65 7 -12 29 -40 50 -62 21 -22 55 -65 75 -95 20 -30 42 -59 48 -65 7 -5 32 -39 57 -75 24 -36 56 -77 71 -91 14 -15 34 -41 43 -59 9 -17 30 -45 46 -62 16 -17 29 -35 29 -40 0 -8 55 -93 70 -108 3 -3 25 -32 49 -65 25 -33 53 -66 63 -73 10 -7 24 -28 32 -45 7 -18 33 -54 57 -82 25 -27 58 -68 74 -90 16 -22 32 -42 35 -45 3 -3 19 -22 34 -42 42 -57 66 -60 394 -54 351 7 398 11 418 40 21 30 50 130 59 201 4 33 10 62 14 65 9 7 46 174 71 320 11 69 25 134 30 145 5 11 21 81 35 155 29 151 65 292 75 300 10 7 30 116 30 160 0 67 58 400 69 400 15 0 67 326 58 362 -11 41 -22 41 -532 29z m-457 -846 c22 -25 30 -85 12 -85 -5 0 -10 -17 -10 -37 0 -36 -23 -181 -33 -213 -3 -8 -8 -27 -11 -42 -5 -23 -12 -28 -35 -28 -22 0 -35 10 -65 54 -21 30 -45 64 -54 75 -9 10 -24 28 -33 39 -9 11 -29 40 -43 65 -15 25 -34 48 -42 51 -8 3 -27 31 -41 62 -37 81 -32 84 172 84 160 0 162 0 183 -25z"></path><path id="pxhpbx6xl" d="M12420 4853 c-69 -2 -135 -5 -148 -8 -41 -10 -51 -48 -93 -372 -11 -87 -24 -160 -28 -163 -4 -3 -11 -36 -14 -75 -8 -84 -31 -264 -58 -438 -10 -70 -19 -138 -19 -152 0 -14 -4 -25 -9 -25 -5 0 -11 -21 -14 -47 -3 -27 -23 -194 -43 -373 -21 -179 -42 -326 -46 -328 -4 -2 -8 -36 -8 -75 0 -107 -20 -101 377 -105 213 -2 346 1 372 8 45 12 57 36 67 129 3 31 9 65 14 76 5 11 16 94 24 185 29 311 66 625 76 642 6 10 10 29 10 43 0 41 28 43 61 5 16 -18 29 -38 29 -46 0 -7 4 -14 9 -16 4 -1 27 -42 49 -89 22 -48 45 -90 51 -94 7 -3 30 -43 52 -87 23 -45 48 -88 56 -97 17 -16 83 -152 83 -169 0 -6 6 -17 13 -24 7 -7 28 -44 47 -81 19 -37 43 -77 53 -87 9 -11 17 -21 17 -24 0 -3 18 -42 39 -88 52 -109 106 -161 184 -178 38 -7 164 -10 395 -8 363 3 380 6 366 52 -11 37 -65 151 -74 156 -12 7 -102 160 -135 227 -14 28 -25 61 -25 72 0 11 -13 34 -30 51 -16 17 -49 65 -72 108 -23 42 -51 86 -61 98 -10 12 -31 49 -47 82 -16 34 -34 68 -40 74 -16 18 -99 156 -156 258 -26 47 -54 92 -62 100 -8 8 -27 42 -42 75 -15 33 -34 68 -42 76 -9 8 -34 51 -57 95 -22 43 -46 85 -52 92 -6 7 -32 50 -57 95 -25 45 -51 87 -57 94 -7 6 -29 45 -49 87 -21 42 -42 76 -46 76 -5 0 -22 29 -39 64 -17 36 -44 78 -60 95 l-30 30 -303 3 c-167 2 -359 2 -428 1z"></path><path id="pA51MyldE" d="M14231 4853 c-183 -4 -201 -10 -201 -66 0 -35 69 -320 80 -327 4 -3 17 -54 29 -115 41 -205 65 -310 72 -315 3 -3 13 -34 22 -70 31 -136 70 -275 77 -280 11 -7 68 -215 91 -330 7 -36 16 -68 21 -71 4 -3 11 -39 14 -81 5 -60 10 -77 24 -81 18 -5 50 -142 50 -216 0 -23 4 -41 8 -41 5 0 16 -19 25 -42 49 -118 55 -122 246 -126 190 -5 566 15 600 31 22 11 26 19 24 55 -2 48 -48 232 -68 277 -8 17 -35 111 -61 210 -25 99 -50 185 -54 190 -5 6 -27 84 -50 175 -23 91 -45 167 -49 170 -7 4 -68 214 -87 295 -4 17 -11 35 -15 41 -5 6 -17 46 -27 90 -28 113 -61 224 -78 259 -8 17 -25 80 -39 140 -13 61 -31 130 -39 153 -28 78 -24 77 -250 78 -111 0 -275 -1 -365 -3z"></path></g></g></svg>
```

[image: SVG Image]
In this site:

[Site Link](http://patchsite.fox_gdminggdmin.repl.co/)

However, unfortunately, it seems to always cut off the right side and bottom side edges of the image, and I can't figure out how to fix it:
[image: The Issue]

I've been trying to figure this out for the past 5 hours or so, so any help would be much appreciated.

I've made an example repl.it, with just the problematic bits:
[Link to Repl.it](http://wryupsetbackground.fox_gdminggdmin.repl.co/)

If anyone needs any more information, or has any suggestions, please, let me know!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some miss configuration in SVG.

I will only talk about the `svg` tag.

The `class` and the `id` attributes are useless, you load the SVG in an image tag, browser won't see these.

`xmlns` attribute is a classic for SVG.

`style`, your problem is here, you put some transformations on your SVG, cropping it on the right and the bottom (the `transform` part), and as for `class` and `id`, some styling will not be used by browser (like the `cursor`)

`width` and `height` may cause problems in resize, better to remove them.

`viewBox`, the great magic in SVG, always must be there.

To simplify, remove everything except `xmlns` and `viewBox`.

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20260 13200">
```

[Basic example with a patched SVG](https://jsfiddle.net/krwa3gp2/)

Comment: This answer is correct, but has buried the important information in the middle of the answer. The tl;dr summary is: **remove the `transform` from your `style` attribute**. The transform shouldn't be there. It is pushing your logo outside of the `viewBox`. The `viewBox` describes the visible content of your SVG.

Comment: This was it, thanks!